# Active Record Relation Has Many Through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have the following models:

```
class FavoriteDirectorSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links
  has_many :directors, through: :links
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :favorite_director_set
  belongs_to :director
end

class Director < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links
  has_many :favorite_director_sets, through: :links
  has_many :movies
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :director
end
```

I have been getting into building queries by chaining scopes together but I'm not clear how to break this one down. How do I create an Active Record Relation object of Movies which match a given FavoriteDirectorSet id?

UPDATE

I have two solutions working ("favourite_director" abbreviated to fd):

1) @rubyman option 1:

```
fd_sets = FDSet.find(:fd_set_id)
res = Movie.where('director_id IN (?)', fd_sets.directors.map(&:id))
```

2) @rubyman option 2:

```
res = Movie.joins(:director=>[:links=>:fd_set]).
    where("fd_sets.id = ?", :fd_set_id)
```

Comment: can't you just join favorite director set on favorite_director_set.fk_director = movie.fk_director ?

Comment: @mkk.  Thanks.  I think that makes sense but I'm afraid you would need to spell it out for me. i.e. you would be saying Movie.joins(:what?)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One Way would be say fds = FavoriteDirectorSet.find(fds_id)

Movie.where('director_id IN (?)', fds.derectors.map(&:id))

OR with joins(not sure about this)

Movie.joins(:director=>[:links=>:favorite_director_sets]).where("favorite_director_sets.id = ?", fds_id)

Comment: Thanks.  Got both of these working.  Had to make one tweak to the second: [:links=>:favorite_director_set] (i.e. "sets" not plural).  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOIN according to the [RubyGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

Syntax I would use is:

```
@movie.joins("INNER JOIN favorite_director_sets ON favorite_director_sets.fk_director = movies.fk_director") # please ensure that table names are correct - if they follow convention, I believe they are correct
```

Now you can just add where condition, i.e. `favorite_director_sets.id = ?, fds_id`

Please note that in your case you might want to use something else than LINNER. On [CoddingHorror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) there is great visual explanation what INNER JOIN means and what are alternatives.

UPDATE:

Please note that the other solution is much simpler, but probably worse performance wise:

```
fds = FavoriteDirectorSet.find(fds_id)
@movies = fds.director.movies
```

or you can even write it in one line:

```
@movies = FavoriteDirectorSet.find(fds_id).director.movies
```

UPDATE: 
This answer is wrong because I forgot about Link table. Rubyman's solution looks fine

Comment: Thanks for this.  I couldn't get this solution working but I'm wondering if I'm missing something.  It does result in less SQL hence I'm interested if there is a faster option I'm missing.  I've edited my question.

Comment: @Derek sorry I misread the question - I forgot about Links table. I believe you should stick to Rubyman's solution.

Comment: No problem.  You got me thinking though ;-)